# Ubuntu Unity 13.04/13.10 systray no longer present

Tags: unity, 13.04, 13.10, system-tray

From what I can tell, a decision was made to remove the systray from 13.04/13.10. I managed to get it re-enabled on my upgrade for now.  What I am not able to find, is the replacement solution for that functionality. Is it just gone, or is there some new solution / application to obtain that functionality?

-mike.

Comment: Does anyone know what the plan is to replace the functionality of the system tray?  Seems like a silly thing to remove the functionality and have no means of replacing it?  How does one know whether Skype / IM is running or not, status etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I've installed cairo-dock (sudo apt-get install cairo-dock).  It has an add-in called "Notification Area Old" which seems to work fairly well.